# Can I create a WDS network over ethernet with multiple Airport Extremes?

Tags: home-networking, airport, wds

I have an Airport Extreme and have ethernet wired through most of my house.  I'd like to add another Airport Extreme/Express to parts of the house where the signal is weak.  I don't want the network the traffic between the routers to go via wireless, but rather over ethernet.  My devices which have an ethernet port are directly wired, but sometimes the iPad/iPhone have a weak signal.  All the instructions I've found indicate having the Airports join each other's wireless network.  Is it possible to get them to work via ethernet, and not in a double-NAT'd fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go the WDS route.  Just add an airport extreme to any available ethernet port in your home. Configure it as a bridge and "Create a Wireless Network".  You can give it the same wireless network name or a different name. Also, don't forget to secure the new network.  I give mine different names so I can know which express I'm connected to.  You will be on the same subnet and have the ability to continue to share folders, timeCapsule, printers, etc....

Apple makes it easy....

Comment: airport extreme OR express.....